# Upload file to a specific folder - AWS S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to upload a file from Node.js application to AWS S3 Bucket.

```
async uploadFile(file: any) {
    try {
      console.log(file);
      const s3Params = {
        Bucket: xyz,
        Key: String(file.originalname),
        Body: file.buffer,
      };

      await s3.upload(s3Params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) return console.log({ err });
        else console.log({ data });
      });
    } catch (error) {
      return { data: null, error, status: 500 };
    }
  }
}
```

Say, if I have a folder inside bucket `xyz` called `/images`, where do I specify this path?

I want the uploaded file to into `/images` directory rather than at the root of the bucket directory.

Comment: As part of the `Key`. `"images/" + String(file.originalname)`!?

Comment: Note that while Windows and Linux root folders begin with `/` e.g. `/tmp` and `/opt`, in S3 you do not supply a leading `/` on keys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Key` of an Amazon S3 object includes the **full path** of the object.

In fact, Amazon does not use folders/directories, so you can simply upload an object with `Key='images/foo.jpg'` and it will 'appear' to be in the `images` directory.

The directory will 'appear' automatically. Then, if all objects in that directory are deleted, then the directory will 'disappear' (because it never actually existed).

In your code, you could use:

```
Key: 'images/' + file.originalname,
```